# Checking for exact value in QGIS raster calculator

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator

I would like to single out values which are equal to a certain floating point value using QGIS raster calculator. I tried to run the following:

`"Converted@1"==-3.40282347*10^38`

But I got the error message:

> Incorrect parameter value for LAYERS

Why does this happen? How can I check for an exact value in QGIS?

Comment: Shouldnt it be only one = sign

Comment: yeah that doesn't make a difference. Still get the same error.